# InnerHtml of HtmlDocument not changing

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to build an email template using html agility pack.
I'm firstly getting the base layout:

```
public static HtmlDocument GetLayout()
        {
            string path = @"Modules\RoomBookingShared\Resources\EmailTemplate.html";
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.Load(path);
            return document;
        }
```

With a created HtmlNode i'm trying to write it to the inner of a specific element in the Html.

```
        public static HtmlDocument SetBody(string body, HtmlDocument document)
        {
            string path = @"Modules\RoomBookingShared\Resources\test.html";
            HtmlDocument item = new HtmlDocument();
            item.Load(path);

            document.GetElementbyId("body-area").ChildNodes.Add(item.DocumentNode);
            FileStream sw = new FileStream("FileStream.html", FileMode.Create);
            document.Save(sw);
            return document;
        }
```

This is not setting and instead is just sending the layout file. What's strange, is if i write out the file (see the filestream code) it writes out the Html file correctly.

The output that should get added (minus data) is the following:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">    
    <tr>
        <td class="fallback-text maven" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #343A40; border: 1px solid #454D55; color: white; text-align: center;">Location</td>
        <td class="fallback-text titillium" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; border: 1px solid #DEE2E6;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fallback-text maven" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #343A40; border: 1px solid #454D55; color: white; text-align: center;">Date & Time</td>
        <td class="fallback-text titillium" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; border: 1px solid #DEE2E6;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fallback-text maven" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #343A40; border: 1px solid #454D55; color: white; text-align: center;">Required </td>
        <td class="fallback-text titillium" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; border: 1px solid #DEE2E6;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fallback-text maven" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #343A40; border: 1px solid #454D55; color: white; text-align: center;">Attendees</td>
        <td class="fallback-text titillium" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; border: 1px solid #DEE2E6;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fallback-text maven" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #343A40; border: 1px solid #454D55; color: white; text-align: center;">Booking Reason</td>
        <td class="fallback-text titillium" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; border: 1px solid #DEE2E6;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="fallback-text maven" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; background-color: #343A40; border: 1px solid #454D55; color: white; text-align: center;">Reference</td>
        <td class="fallback-text titillium" style="padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px; mso-height-rule: exactly; border: 1px solid #DEE2E6;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please add samples of file written by stream and response ?

Comment: @AdityaBhave example of what should be added is now in the question

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be to do with ParsedText and Text.
To fix this, i had to use the following:

```
Body = final.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```